# Using stack, ghc-mod and NixOS all together

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix, ghc-mod

I'm having some trouble getting all these tools to work together, and I would be interested to hear if someone has managed.

My main problem is the following: I have some external dependencies, which in my `stack.yaml` look like this:

```
nix:
  enable: true
  packages: [curl, postgresql94, zlib]
```

which are clearly provided by the nix system. When I run `ghc-mod type Main.hs 39 19` on my current `Main.hs` I get the following:

```
EXCEPTION: types:
           <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /home/user/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nix/lts-7.15/8.0.1/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.0.1/postgresql-libpq-0.9.2.0-IWEdPrPraPeE94ud73Ope3/libHSpostgresql-libpq-0.9.2.0-IWEdPrPraPeE94ud73Ope3-ghc8.0.1.so (libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

so it seems to be having trouble loading these external dependencies.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: You could try [Intero](https://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/), which is specifically made to work well with `stack`. The more difficult way would be to package `ghc-mod` for Nix.

Comment: @Mikkel: thanks, but I'm a vim guy :) there is already a nix package for ghc-mod, I don't think that's the problem here, or maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I think that stack's nix integration only installs the dependencies in a nix-shell that it uses internally. Is it possible that your ghc-mod is running outside of this shell, and therefore missing some of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` entries it needs?